# How do I check if a date is between several ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between, range

I have a few date ranges:

```
01/01/2010 - 03/01/2010
05/01/2010 - 06/01/2010
08/01/2010 - 16/01/2010
```

Is it possible in SQL to check if a date like `02/01/2010` is between any of these ranges?

Comment: Just use Or statements is too complicated / inappropriate ?

Comment: Or statement is ok, but I don't know how many ranges i will have...

Comment: That what I was thinking by asking my naive question. So you should describe that part of the problem in your question, if you want good answers ;)

Comment: which datatype you are using for date column ?

Comment: I am using datetime2(7)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      DateFrom DATETIME
    , DateTo DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (DateFrom, DateTo)
VALUES 
    ('20100101', '20100103'),
    ('20100105', '20100106')

IF EXISTS(
     SELECT 1
     FROM @temp
     WHERE '20100102' BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo
)
     PRINT '2010-01-02 between any of these ranges'
```

Comment: It's ok but i don't know how many ranges i will have, so How I can fill temp table?

Comment: This is only a small sample. Just replace `@temp` to `your_table_name` in SELECT block.